# Alter max simultaneous connections from Javascript?

Tags: javascript, browser

I am trying to measure bandwidth from a web page application. I find that I can increase accuracy by initiating more simultaneous downloads (or uploads).

I have seen many answers describing browser built-in limits from `about:config` - network.http.max-persistent-connections-per-proxy and network.http.max-persistent-connections-per-server (see, for example, [Max parallel http connections in a browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985431/max-parallel-http-connections-in-a-browser/26883234#26883234) )

I would not want to permanently affect the built-in values shown by `about:config`. Is there a way for Javascript to change these values for the current browser window? Thanks.

**Update:** As noted by commenters, there is probably no way to increase the limit. Some speed test sites use multiple servers to establish more simultaneous connections. Thanks!

Comment: No, there's no way for the js code in a website to change these, otherwise they wouldn't be limits.

Comment: You want to change the value with no user interaction? That's unlikely to happen.

Comment: Yeah. I suspected as much. I have seen other speed test programs that launch as many as 30 simultaneous transfers - I need to disassemble their requests... Thanks!

Comment: They might be using multiple servers.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the case. Thanks!